# iphone- Google Calendar

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, google-calendar-api

In an app, I want to use Google Calendar. Now my requirement is I get the mail id and events from the user. And now i want to display those events (events means user given in my app) into that particular given mail id (username mail calendar). But without using iphone ical. I want to directly add to the particular mail calendar. (for instance: `mail id: xx@gmail.com, event: "title:"meeting" on date: "6-2-2013""` - I get this information from my app). Now i want to go into that `xxx@gmail.com` and i want to show the events (meeting on 6-2-2013) in that mail calendar. How can i do this without using iCal?